# How to extend a div backwards?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Does anyone know how to extend a div 2 to the back, lowering the div 1 to the down, when clicking, in a simple way? It looks easy but with css it is not possible and with javascript it is difficult.

I want when clicking on the 2 extends back and the 1 goes down:

[image: the extends]

But instead this happens:

[image: the div two go down]

div 2 goes down.

Html and Css:

```css
.frame {
    width: 50%;
    height: 400px;
    font: bold 70px roboto;
    color: black;
    background-color: yellow;
    float: left;

}

input:checked + .frame {
    width: 100%;

}

input{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<body class="gallery">
  <input type="checkbox" id="a" />
  <label for="a" class="frame a">1</label>

  <input type="checkbox" id="b" />
  <label for="b" class="frame b" style="background-color: green">2</label>

  <input type="checkbox" id="c" />
  <label for="c" class="frame a" style="background-color: green">3</label>

  <input type="checkbox" id="d" />
  <label for="d" class="frame b">4</label>
</body>
```

I tried with this javascript:

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/wooddocu/xwpo0mng/15/)

Comment: To "move" elements like this, you are effectively re-ordering the elements.

Comment: Jon P Show me how with js. Is it possible with css?

Comment: so what happens to 3/4/5/6?

Comment: epascarello They are also moved down, check out the javascript demo: https://jsfiddle.net/wooddocu/xwpo0mng/12/

Comment: This sounds like a job for CSS grid with named template areas: give each div its own named area, write (or generate) a bunch of classes for all the combinations, then just use JS to change the outer div class to whatever is the one you need?

Comment: Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans Explain that about changing classes, but i already tried with css grid, grid-area, grid-column, order, flexbox, grid with float and javascript with insertBefore and i didn't succeed

Comment: You need _multiple_ grid definitions, all with different classes, then you change the class that determines which grid area has what name using parent.classList.remove to get rid of the old class with the grid definition, and parent.classList.add to add the new class with a completely different grid definition

Comment: Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans What CSS grid property are you referring to?

Answer (score 2):

**To Make the clicked div moves above all:**

You can easily do that:

1-Make the `gallery` parent `flex`

2-Give `order: 2;` for all children

3-Change the `order` to `1` when checked

**Apply:**

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.frame {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100px;
    font: bold 70px roboto;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    order: 2;
}

input:checked + .frame {
    width: 100%;
    order: 1;
}

input{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<body class="gallery">
    <input type="checkbox" id="a"/>
    <label for="a" class="frame" style="outline: 2px solid">1</label>

    <input type="checkbox" id="b"/>
    <label for="b" class="frame" style="outline: 2px solid">2</label>

    <input type="checkbox" id="c"/>
    <label for="c" class="frame" style="outline: 2px solid">3</label>

    <input type="checkbox" id="d"/>
    <label for="d" class="frame" style="outline: 2px solid">4</label>

    <input type="checkbox" id="e"/>
    <label for="e" class="frame" style="outline: 2px solid">5</label>

    <input type="checkbox" id="f"/>
    <label for="f" class="frame" style="outline: 2px solid">6</label>
</body>
```

And now, when you click anyone, it will go to the top and fill the parent width.

And when you click another one while the first is still active, it will be move to the top too and fill the parent width without affecting the older one.

If you want to stop having many frames selected at the top, just turn your inputs to be `radio` instead of `checkbox` and connect them all with the same `name` attribute.

---

---

**To make the clicked div moves above its brother only:**

Here you must dived every two frames in a separate row div and do the same job for the rest.

**Apply:**

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.row {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.frame {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100px;
    font: bold 70px roboto;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    order: 2;
}

input:checked + .frame {
    width: 100%;
    order: 1;
}

input {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<body class="gallery">
    <div class="row">
        <input type="checkbox" id="a" />
        <label for="a" class="frame" style="outline: 2px solid">1</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="b" />
        <label for="b" class="frame" style="outline: 2px solid">2</label>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <input type="checkbox" id="c" />
        <label for="c" class="frame" style="outline: 2px solid">3</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="d" />
        <label for="d" class="frame" style="outline: 2px solid">4</label>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <input type="checkbox" id="e" />
        <label for="e" class="frame" style="outline: 2px solid">5</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="f" />
        <label for="f" class="frame" style="outline: 2px solid">6</label>
    </div>
</body>
```

Now if you clicked a div, it will go above its brother only, there is a small difference that the other elements will not merge with its brother.

---

---

And absolutely there is many many many other ways using css or javascript, but I think the first one does what you want.

Comment: In the first example all the divs are moved to the back. I want only the clicked div to change order.

In the second you could click only on the 2 in the others not.                                                                   I already tried with css grid, grid-area, grid-column, order, flexbox, grid with float and javascript with insertBefore and i didn't succeed

Comment: @Table
I added another solution at the end of my answer, I hope that's what you mean.
If not, so please explain your idea more, so I can decide which way is helpful and give it to you.

Comment: Ahmed M.Znaty In the last solution how can I add css styles and pseudo classes to thousands of divs as they load? I am creating a gallery of photos and texts that is loaded as the scroll

Comment: i think i need a javascript to add thousands of css properties to the divs thats the hard part

Comment: Ok, I got the full idea except one thing, if you can clear it to me it will be great to be able to help more.
But absolutely it will be done in javascript not css, but the question now, Do you want the clicked item to be above all items or just above the element directly next to it. And if the second is your case, so Is always the row will contain just two items or it can be bigger? after clarifying these points I can try to find a solution in javascript.

Comment: Ahmed M.Znaty Above all but show me how you would do both options.

Rows have 2 elements and show me how you would do it with more.

Comment: @Table I changed the full answer, now I think it's how you need. If it's not, just let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Nice question. Yep, it does not have pure-css solution, unfortunately...

Fully agree with previous comment regarding to "swapping" strategy via "order" css property. It's definitely less code and more performant then "physically moving" html elements in DOM

Also, "display: grid" is always better then flex for multi-dimensional layouts (2-column in our case)

Supposing that initial requirement expects that any "even cell" should behave as "2", I see full solution like this:

```js
const el_cells = document.querySelectorAll('.wrapper .cell');

el_cells.forEach((el_clicked, index) => {
    const el_prev = index > 0 ? el_cells[index - 1] : null;

    el_clicked.addEventListener('click', () => {
        // checking if element was already expanded
        const expanding = !el_clicked.classList.contains('active')

        // restoring initial cells state
        el_cells.forEach((el, i) => {
            el.classList.remove('active');
            el.style.order = i + 1;
        });

        if (expanding) {
            // resizing selected cell
            el_clicked.classList.add('active');

            // swapping 'even' cell with previous one (f.e. 2 with 1, 4 with 3, etc...)
            if (index % 2 === 1) {
                el_clicked.style.order--;
                el_prev.style.order++;
            }
        }
    })
})
```

```css
/* some not very important global styles */
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

/* our yellow-green grid */
.wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

.wrapper .cell {
    height: 100px;
    background: yellow;
}

.wrapper .cell.green {
    background: green;
}

.wrapper .cell.active {
    grid-column: span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="cell">1</div>
    <div class="cell green">2</div>
    <div class="cell green">3</div>
    <div class="cell">4</div>
    <div class="cell">5</div>
    <div class="cell green">6</div>
    <div class="cell green">7</div>
    <div class="cell">8</div>
</div>
```

Improved this example a bit to make expanded cells to collapse on click :)

Comment: Uladzimir Interesting, when you click on 2 it extends, then you click on 4 and everyone else resets.

Can you tell me how to keep the 2 extended after clicking another one?

Comment: Uladzimir I need the div to stay extended

Answer (score 1):

*"Uladzimir Interesting, when you click on 2 it extends, then you click on 4 and everyone else resets. Can you tell me how to keep the 2 extended after clicking another one?"*

Well, this small clarification adds additional "layer of complexity" to the initial question :)

The reason is that when initially you click "2" - you know that all "even elements" should push "odd ones" below them. On the other hand, when "2" gets expanded and you click "5" - how system should behave if not getting "2" collapsed ?
[image]

Seems that "5" has to push "4" below like "2" did that with "1".
[image]
So now logics of re-ordering elements has to become "generic" not like it was previously (re-ordering even-index elements when clicked)

And now user clicks, for example, "3", how to process this situation then ? Where do we have to push "1" in this case ? Under "5" probably ? I do not know... But, you see, lots of "edge cases" start appearing here...

What's bad here is that if you implement that - the solution would be definitely bulky, dirty and not very readable and understandable, unfortunately... So, I think, the best way here - to suggest your customers some easier-to-implement option (for example as I suggested initially when collapsing previously expanded elements)

Just a possible and not "too complicated" variant is to list selected elements always "on top":

```js
const el_cells = document.querySelectorAll('.wrapper .cell');
let el_expanded = [];

el_cells.forEach((el_clicked) => {
    el_clicked.addEventListener('click', () => {
        const expanding = !el_clicked.classList.contains('active');

        // resizing/collapsing current cell
        if (expanding) {
            el_clicked.classList.add('active');
        } else {
            el_clicked.classList.remove('active');
        }

        // refreshing expanded element collection
        if (expanding) {
            el_expanded = [el_clicked, ...el_expanded];
        } else {
            el_expanded = el_expanded.filter(_ => _ !== el_clicked);
        }

        // re-indexing not-expanded elements
        el_cells.forEach((el, idx) => {
            if (el_expanded.indexOf(el) !== -1) return;
            el.style.order = 1000 + idx + 1     // 1000 added here to list them after "expanded" ones
        })

        // re-indexing expanded elements
        el_expanded.forEach((el, idx) => {
            el.style.order = idx + 1;
        })
    });
});
```

```css
/* some not very important global styles */
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

/* our yellow-green grid */
.wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

.wrapper .cell {
    height: 100px;
    background: yellow;
}

.wrapper .cell.green {
    background: green;
}

.wrapper .cell.active {
    grid-column: span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="cell">1</div>
    <div class="cell green">2</div>
    <div class="cell green">3</div>
    <div class="cell">4</div>
    <div class="cell">5</div>
    <div class="cell green">6</div>
    <div class="cell green">7</div>
    <div class="cell">8</div>
</div>
```

Again, this is not "ideal" option, you see. With lots of elements in list it would also require some "scroll-to-top" logics :( Anyway, it is understandable, predictable and requires "not too much" code to create and maintain